# Help with JQuery conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, if-statement

I am trying to run some JQuery script on a particular page but only if a certain page loads.

The Scenario:  We have one page that loads (i.e., webpage.aspx) and it loads different content based on the referring click. (i.e., webpage.aspx?contentId=1, webpage.aspx?contentId=2, webpage.aspx?contentId=3, etc).  Here is my problem.  I need to have a particular part of the page removed if only one specific contentId is pulled.  I am trying to do this in JQuery and can't seem to figure it out.

Here's what i have been working with so far.  I realize it's not correct but hopefully it gives you a starting point to work with.

Thanks.

CODE:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var $deleteNewRow = $("div.col.w140 tbody:first").find("td:first").parent().remove();
   if($('#dealer-info h1').indexOf('Ferrari') != -1) {
      $deleteNewRow
   }
});
```

Comment: Basically, i'm looking on the content pulled to see if it is the Ferrari content.  If it IS i am deleting something from the page.  But i only want to delete it for the Ferrari content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you store in your `$deleteNewRow` variable isn't the jQuery method, that method will already execute.  You want to do that method in your if statement, something like this (note that you are also missing the `.text()` in the if statement):

```
$(window).load(function() {
   if($('#dealer-info h1').text().indexOf('Ferrari') != -1) {
      $("div.col.w140 tbody:first").find("td:first").parent().remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `:contains` selector to check for the existence. Here is the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
Then to delete find the element and then use `remove`.

```
$("div.col.w140 tbody:first").find("td:first").parent().remove();
```

Comment: can you help me by writing out the first part of the code (the part that has the "contains" in it)?

Comment: if($("#dealer-info").find("h1:contains('Ferrari')")){
   $(".col.w140 tbody:first").find("td:first").parent().remove();
}else{
}


The $("#dealer-info").find("h1:contains('Ferrari')") IS selecting the h1 only if it has Ferrari in it...however, the IF statement is not running properly.